# PHP if clause is not working any ideas why?

Tags: php

```
 if ($subtotal1 != 0 or $subtotal2 != 0 or $subtotal3 != 0 or $subtotal4 != 0    )

  {

  echo $compno.' '.$subtotal1.' '.$subtotal2.' '.$subtotal3.' '.$subtotal4;
  echo "<br>";

  $info4 =array($compno, $total);

 }
```

The if block is getting executed even if one of the values of the $subtotal(n) is 0.

Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like you want to replace the `or` with `&&`

Comment: You've used `or`, so the `if` block will execute if any one of the terms is non-zero. You probably want to use `and` or preferably `&&`.

Comment: This is one of the most common errors. I've frequently see this error in answers, not just questions.

Comment: If any one of the subtotals is zero the if block should not execute. If I use &&, it always needs to have all the 4 subtotals to be zeros right?

Comment: @user2442708 If you use `&&`, it needs all the 4 variables NOT to be 0 for the code to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use && instead of or, cause your if condition will get executed even one of your value is non-zero.

Using or in if statement simply means if any of the condition is true, execute the code.

Using && means execute the if statement if all the conditions are true. Thanks it make it more clear

```
if ($subtotal1 != 0 && $subtotal2 != 0 && $subtotal3 != 0 && $subtotal4 != 0    )

  {

  echo $compno.' '.$subtotal1.' '.$subtotal2.' '.$subtotal3.' '.$subtotal4;
  echo "<br>";

  $info4 =array($compno, $total);

 }
```

Try this

```
if($subtotal1 != 0){
}

    elseif($subtotal2 != 0){

    }elseif($subtotal3 != 0)
    {

    }
    elseif($subtotal3 != 0)
    {

    }
else 
{
    echo $compno.' '.$subtotal1.' '.$subtotal2.' '.$subtotal3.' '.$subtotal4;
  echo "<br>";

  $info4 =array($compno, $total); 
}
```

Comment: Worked Arif Suhail. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it should NOT execute IF just ONE of the subtotal values is zero. If ALL the values are non-zeroes it should only execute then.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change "or" to "and".

`if ($subtotal1 != 0 and $subtotal2 != 0 and $subtotal3 != 0 and $subtotal4 != 0    )`

Comment: If any one of the subtotals is zero the if block should not execute.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what will happen with the above code. If you use "and" it makes sure that none of the subtotals would be zero. Let me put it for you in simple terms. if(apple1!=rotten and apple2!=rotten) makeApplePie(); So if either one of the apples is rotten, no pie!

Comment: Just checked and it works! You made my day Joey Ezekiel.

Comment: if you like the answer, you could buy me a beer -lol. But for now, an accept/upvote would do ;)